# My SSD has unexpected inconsistencies showing up after some time of usage

Tags: filesystems, boot, ssd, lock

I have Ubuntu installed on my Kingston SSD.

```
4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The system itself is quite smooth, but I have a major data storage problem.
Everything seems to work fine:

- all software runs well,
- badblocks sees no problem with the hard drive,
- BUT from time to time, the whole drive becomes READ only.

I can't save anything, can't remount it, nothing. I have to reboot the whole thing.

It seems to happen at random, but I THINK the OS freezes for a couple of seconds when It happens. I am not sure if it is the case as I was unable to confirm it. The freezing sometimes happens randomly as well and the drive is still usable.

All in all, random freezes happen frequently, but they shouldn't - this is quite a good setup - 16 GB ram, 32 gb swap, ryzen 7 2xxx series. The freezes last up to 20 seconds, and then the PC resumes it's operation. If a freeze happens during (for example) playing a game, I'm getting disconnected from the server.

But, back to the problem, when the PC freezes, I have to reboot it, modify run options, type in `nomodeset`, and then run fsck manually on `/dev/sda1`. This fixes the problem and the PC is fine for the next couple days, then I have to repeat the process. The error I'm getting in fsck is about orphaned nodes, some kind of journals, inconsistencies, etc.

Honestly I have no idea how to fix this problem. Any clues?

So I took some photos while fixing the error:

- Initial Error:

  [image]
- During Fixing #1:

  [image]
- During Fixing #2:

  [image]

I have also noticed, that when I try to shutdown the PC after the filesystem becomes read only, it waits up to ten minutes for mysql to stop. I am not sure if MySQL causes the problem, or the PC waits because it cannot write to the hard drive. My second drive is perfectly functional.

@Edit
I have a completely new setup, only the SSD remains. Still, the same problem. I have replaced the SATA cable and checked that it is plugged in correctly. Is there any way to resolve this problem now?

@Edit2

I have checked with badblocks and smartctl - no errors are seen on the hard drive.